# How to use Proxy engine in Apache to redirect to other subdomain mapped to other host?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain, cloudflare, mod-proxy

I'm trying to create an "alias" of a subdomain. The problem is that this subdomain is mapped to other hosting, so rule fails because it didn't find the subdomain in the current host. I'd need to tell Apache to "redirect" (not changing URL, that's why I'm using mod_proxy) querying the DNS again. I'm not sure this is possible or I'm missing some concepts about proxy engine.

DNS (CloudFlare):

```
aaa.example.com => ...herokudns.com (Quoters)
bbb.example.com => AWS IP (my EC2 instance)
```

In My EC2 instance, Apache:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerAlias bbb.example.com

    SSLProxyEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bbb\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://aaa.example.com/%1/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm getting a 404 that is being logged in my EC2 instance, so I assume it's trying to find `aaa.example.com` inside the same hosting.

Access log:

```
example.com:80 186.18.xxx.xxx - - [04/Jul/2019:15:14:19 -0300] "GET /show/53pVJGO8e HTTP/1.1" 404 483 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11..."
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Even if solution comes with some rule inside CloudFlare. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare has a [KB article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-Cloudflare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS) describing how you could create a CNAME to Heroku.
You can also use Page Rules [Host Header Override](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206652947-Using-Page-Rules-to-Re-Write-Host-Headers) or [Resolve Override](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206190798-Using-Resolve-Override-in-Page-Rules), but these features are only available for Enterprise plans.
If the jump to Enterprise is too huge for you, you can even [use Workers to achieve similar result](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/cloudflare-features/#resolve-override).

Comment: Thank you man. I'm on a free plan. I checked out the docs in CF (https://workers.cloudflare.com/docs/reference/runtime/apis/fetch/#the-cf-object since the other one is deprecated) to read about "resolve override" param in Request object. It looks like pretty much the thing I need, but it's an enterprise feature even to implement in workers scripts. I made some tests but it didn't work (cf is always empty), so I couldn't change origin directly from there.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not working directly with Heroku. I'm using Quoters and they manage domain aliases with Heroku, so I can't do any magics there since they say "point this CNAME to sadsadsa.heroku and it will resolve to blabla.example.com". CNAME from CNAME didn't work (as expected...).